# Função Checkout é suportada no Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-online

Hoje estamos num time pequeno de desenvolvimento, somos em 3 pessoas. Uma pergunta, o Visual Studio Team Services tem essa função ou precisamos de um servidor para com o TFS instalado só para essa função?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível ter a função Check-out no VSTS.

Isso porque quem determina a disponibilidade dessa função não é o serviço (TFS ou VSTS), mas sim uma combinação de dois fatores:

1. O tipo de repositório em uso, que deve ser TFVC (Git não suporta o conhecido de check-out); e
2. O tipo de workspace na máquina do desenvolvedor, que deve ser do tipo Server (workspaces locais não mantém o status dos arquivos em check-out no servidor).

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite,

No Azure Devops temos dois tipos de repositórios:

- Azure Repos Git (Padrão)
- Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC)

Para habilitar o TFVC, você deve realizar os seguintes passos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após este procedimento, você poderá acessar o repositório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Visual Studio, fica da mesma forma para se trabalhar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**DICA:**

Avalie de utilizar essa a extension “Branch Visualization”.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.BranchVisualization&targetId=298b943e-d547-4b04-b8cf-01b4dfe97f18&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList